# How to read data (characters) from serial port in Kernel mode (Linux)?

Tags: linux, module, serial-port

I'm developing a linux kernel module and I need to read data from serial port (characters).
I want to set characters (example : 'D' , 'T' and '-') as entries coming from serial port and I want read these entries. I spent a long period trying with "inb(0x3f8)" and "termios" but it didn't work out. However writing data work correctly with "outb"
I have Ubuntu 10.10 as System installed as guest on VirtualBox
on VBox configuration I set :

```
   activated serial port
   port number :   COM1    IRQ 4  PORT I/O : 0x3f8
   Port/path   D:\Oracle\serial.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't have your code run in user-space and make use of the existing serial drivers?  Some very clever folks have written serial drivers for a number of serial port chipsets, and you would save yourself a lot of time if you didn't try to replicate their work.

Comment: I tried, either user and Kernel space, and I'm using an existing serial drivers. further I can write on the file "/dev/ttyS0", but when I try to read froM it , I get thE program blocked or I get a segment ERROR. I think that it should work with polling , interrupts and threads, but I don't know how ? :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think if you run in a kernel thread, it is possible to use filp_open, or some other function to gain a file operations pointer, which you can then use "normal" calls on via the file_operations pointer.

This *only* works if you're running in a "normal" context - of a "user" process or *possibly* kernel-thread, it definitely won't work correctly if you're in some "unusual" context.

In a normal task, these calls can be blocking, and everything will "just work". I think. I have tried it with sockets and it works.

You might have an issue with mounted filesystems, because kernel threads might get a namespace which contains few (or no) file nodes. This might mean that it's easier to open the device in userspace and pass it through in some way.

Also be aware of the limited stack size in the kernel.

Comment: thanks alot, looks like, that these solutions are so difficult for a new comer to the kernel developping field !.

Comment: thanks alot, looks like that these solutions are so difficult for a new comer to the kernel developping field !. I found a little (not real) solution. I made the folder "D:\Oracle" (containing the file of serial port redirection) shared among guest and host, and I

Comment: access the file "serial.txt" from userspace using "fopen" and "fgets"